# javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No transactional EntityManager available

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, orm, transactions

I'm struggling with this exception since yesterday... I checked almost everything, googled all links and I found nothing.

I'm always getting an exception **javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No transactional EntityManager available** when I call addCategory or removeCategory from category service. I attached all necessary configuration files.

I want make Spring handle transactions.

**jpaContext.xml** - in resources folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="emf"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true"></property>
            </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"></entry>
                <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"></entry>
                <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"></entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shopify?autoReconnect=true" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**persistence.xml** - in /META-INF/

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="punit">

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

**web.xml** - fragment, where I load contexts

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:/jpaContext.xml
        /WEB-INF/security-config.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

**category service**

```
package com.example.service;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.example.dao.CategoryDao;
import com.example.Category;


@Service
public class CategoryService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("categoryDaoDatabase")
    private CategoryDao categoryDao;

    @Transactional
    public void addCategory(Category category) {
        category.setId(getLastCategoryId() + 1);
        categoryDao.addCategory(category);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void removeCategory(Category category) {
        categoryDao.removeCategory(category);
    }

    public void setCategoryDao(CategoryDao categoryDao) {
        this.categoryDao = categoryDao;
    }

}
```

**category dao**

```
package com.example.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.domain.Category;


@Repository
public class CategoryDaoDatabase implements CategoryDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void addCategory(Category category) {
        entityManager.persist(category);
        entityManager.flush();
    }

    public void removeCategory(Category category) {
        entityManager.remove(category);
    }

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
}
```

**Maven dependencies - pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Regards,
Tom

**EDIT - solution**

As M. Deinum provided a solution, the problem was, that I put

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
```

in jpaContext.xml, where I didn't load all classes (they are loaded in shopify-servlet.xml - my main app context). I moved the above lines to my main context (shopify-servlet.xml), where I did component-scan, which scans and loads all controllers, services, repositories to the main context, so now @Transactional works :).

Comment: For starters don't mix versions of a framework you are mixing 4.1.0, 4.1.1 and 4.1.4 of spring, don't. If you have a `DispatcherServlet` make sure you aren't scanning for the same components again as that will lead to duplicate instances with the last one not having AOP applied.

Comment: I set everything to 4.1.0, then to 4.1.4, I checked all dependencies. It still didn't work.
This is my web.xml: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=k5KKbMms

btw. I have component-scan only on shopify-servlet (main context)

Comment: Which basically explains your problem. Your component scan should be in the same xml as the `<tx;annotation-driven />` else nothing will happen. AOP is only applied to beans in the same context not on parent or child contexts.

Comment: Also when doing component-scanning make sure you aren't detecting the components twice as that will result in the same error. As a rule of thumb, your `ContextLoaderListener` should scan for everything BUT web related beans (`@COntroller` etc.) where as your `DispatcherServlet` should ONLY scan for web related beans.

Comment: @M.Deinum it's working! Thank you very much!! :)

I'll add your answers to my question, since they're very useful :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an earlier post already pointed out - NEVER mix versions like this.

You can use  to enforce/lock down to a set version and if you use the neat "bill of materials" (bom) resource you remove the need to specify versions like this in multiple locations (with the clear risk of missing something down the track) - This feature also remove any transitive dependencies across your dependency tree.

If you also have a need for spring-security you can lock it down to springframework v4.0.2.RELEASE 
 - According to spring doco (http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#maven-bom) this is the max version that has been fully verified to work with spring-security 3.2.5.RELEASE. When you use the bom all spring-security's springframework v3.2.8.RELEASE resources will be brought up to spingframework v4.0.2.RELEASE automatically.

Comment: where is the solution?